# Detached head message lists incorrect tag name

Tags: git

Can anyone explain this? I had tag `1.13.0` checked out, fetched, then checked out `2.0.4`. The two tags point to very different states of the code. The files appear to be correct for `2.0.4`.

```
# git checkout 2.0.4
HEAD is now at a2a6727... Version change in default configuration.
# git status
HEAD detached from 1.13.0
nothing to commit, working directory clean
# git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

This is on a Beaglebone running Debian 8.

Comment: I'm confused. You checked out `2.0.4` and you say the files are correct for `2.0.4` - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I expected "HEAD detached from 2.0.4" as that is what I am accustomed to. Perhaps my interpretation of the tag name in this message is misguided.

Answer (score 1):

The `git status` message:

```
HEAD detached from 1.13.0
```

(or the same with `detached at ...`) depends on the entries in the reflog.  It's possible that this particular bug, which appears to amount to "retrieving the wrong information from the reflog" (so that it says "detached from 1.13.0" instead of "detached at 2.0.4") was fixed in a later version of Git, although there is nothing to this effect in the release notes.

In any case, if you check out a branch by name in between checking out specific tags, that will probably work around the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out master then the tag and now see `detached from 2.0.4`. I upgrade these systems using saltstack so I'll have to investigate a solution using that tool.